# How to create a jeditable form using formtastic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic, jeditable

I want to create a jeditable form using formtastic in rails3

I have created a model student with name attribute through scaffolding.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= semantic_form_for @student do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>

    <%= f.input :name %><p class="editable" id="paragraph_1">click to enter name</p>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, :as => :input %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

jquery in application.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input.ui-date-picker').datepicker();

      $(".editable").editable("students#update", { 
      indicator : "<img src='img/indicator.gif'>",
      type   : 'textarea',
      name: 'student_name',
      submitdata: { _method: "put" },
      select : true,
      submit : 'OK',
      cancel : 'cancel',
      cssclass : "editable"
  });
```

The rest are as per scaffolding.

I want to save data that came via jeditable in place of 'click to enter name'. How to achive that?